RouterMaster not recognized in main.dart
I just started learning flutter yesterday. Routemaster package is not recognized but only in the main.dart file. what could be the cause of this? I have tried flutter clean, flutter pub get, flutter upgrade packages. also tried to add routematser dependency several times.

